# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing autosub

Tags: pip, python-3.6, egg

I tried to install [Autosub](https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub) but it shown error, and I cannot find a solution that work for me.

I already installed ffmpeg that required by Autosub and added path for it.

I also upgraded my setuptools.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install autosub
Collecting autosub
  Using cached autosub-0.3.11.tar.gz
Collecting google-api-python-client>=1.4.2 (from autosub)
  Using cached google_api_python_client-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from autosub)
Collecting pysrt>=1.0.1 (from autosub)
  Using cached pysrt-1.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting progressbar>=2.3 (from autosub)
  Using cached progressbar-2.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\CHEKWE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wnmhm6k\progressbar\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import progressbar
      File "C:\Users\CHEKWE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wnmhm6k\progressbar\progressbar\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
        from progressbar.widgets import *
      File "C:\Users\CHEKWE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wnmhm6k\progressbar\progressbar\widgets.py", line 121, in <module>
        class FileTransferSpeed(Widget):
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\abc.py", line 133, in __new__
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
    ValueError: 'format' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CHEKWE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-4wnmhm6k\progressbar\
```

I found another answer that said enter `easy_install -U setuptools` but shown error too. (cmd is run as admin)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>easy_install -U setuptools
Searching for setuptools
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Best match: setuptools 35.0.1
Processing setuptools-35.0.1-py3.6.egg
setuptools 35.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install-script.py script to c:\program files\python36\Scripts
Installing easy_install.exe script to c:\program files\python36\Scripts
error: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\Scripts\\easy_install.exe'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Error install pip

"python setup.py egg_info"

**Solution**

Install Python 2.7 uninstall 3.x

https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub/issues/31

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem while running an Alpine Docker container, which was the case for me. Try adding the following line to your `Dockerfile` to install required dependencies.

```
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
```